# Passing touches to Another Sibling UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

As pictured below, I have a subview with a tap gesture attached to it.

When it's tapped, a popup view with its own view controller would be presented in the superview. At this time, the subview and the new popup view would be siblings inside of the superview. Popup view will have its own table view.

[image]

How do I pass the touch that is already down on the subview to the new popup view? Is this possible?

This behaviour could be seen on the new iOS context menus. The touch down that is used to envoke the popup menu could be use to select the choices on the popup menu.

Comment: In UIKit it starts with LongPress, not with tap. And it's way more complicated than it seems. https://developer.limneos.net/index.php?ios=14.4&framework=UIKitCore.framework&header=_UIPreviewPlatterPresentationController.h

Comment: I see that.. But is there a simple way to 'forward' a touch from one view to another?

Comment: Define "forward"? Touch has states, and in all of the states it is delivered to the hit-tested view. You can override which view gets hit-tested, but touches will be delivered first to gesture recognizers on the hit-tested view and on its superviews,  and then if touches aren't cancelled in view, to the view itself and to next responders in the chain.

Comment: Looking at the above pic, the touch from the purple view needs to get forwarded to the green view. They both are siblings, in the same heiarchy.

Comment: Repeating of the word "forward(ed)" does not define the ideal state. You can easily delegate `touchesMoved` call from subview to the popup view. Does it become "forwarded"?

Comment: I believe 'delegating' touchesMoved from subview to popup view is what I am looking for...

Comment: But such delegation will not trigger any gesture recognizer that is attached to popup view.

Comment: That is fine, I can work with Touches Moved